# Let's delete typo comments when they've been fixed

Tags: discussion, comments

Comments on small typos in posts are definitely helpful, and when the typos are few enough, it's not possible to suggest a direct edit. After being fixed by the original poster or a moderator, however, these comments are nothing but noise.

I suggest that we remove such comments. Are there other opinions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From my post on meta.stackoverflow.com:

[**Should moderators delete “make correction… done” comments?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77373/should-moderators-delete-make-correction-done-comments)

> These types of comment discussions are pretty common:
>
> - @AuthorX: In your post, I think you meant "you're", not "your". <sub><sup>- *user1234 35 mins ago*</sup></sub>
> - Oh, thanks. It's fixed now. <sub><sup>- *AuthorX 30 minutes ago*</sup></sub>
>
> Once resolved, those comments are useless and noise.
>
> As a user, I was always wary about deleting my own part in those conversations because it would leave the other user's comment looking orphaned or silly. But as a moderator, I have delete-access to *both* ends of the conversation.
>
> Do you think users will take offense if **these no-longer-relevant comment threads are *summarily* deleted** as a matter of general policy?

While there was no official "policy" established, it has been well-established that that these types of comment-removals are perfectly legitimate (**and even beneficial**).

Comment: Thanks, I missed that post. I won't hesitate the next time.

Answer (score 5):

I definitely agree. In my opinion, if you as a moderator are *100% sure* that the comments are obsolete and not helpful anymore, just go ahead and delete them. Here's an example where I thought it might be helpful to leave my comment at least for some time, since it's not about a simple typo: [Wann verwendet man „zu“ mit dem Infinitiv?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1591)

Personally, when I leave a comment indicating minor typos, I delete the comment myself as soon as the typos are fixed. Sometimes the author of the post leaves some "Thanks, done" type comment; then I also ask the author to remove that comment, and after the removal of the authors comment I remove my follow-up comment. (Yes, that's a bit messy.)

Comment: Actually, it was your cleaning upp your own comments that prompted this post. I just didn't want to go around deleting others' comments without a meta post to point to.

Comment: Regarding the example that you linked to, I think that it still adds value to the post. (As opposed to my following thankyou-comment :))